# Restart activity after user turn wifi on

Tags: android, android-activity, android-wifi

I override *onReceivedError* to create a dialog to let the user turn on the wifi if it is off.

My code there is something like:

```
if (! mWifi.isConnected() ) {

  Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
  startActivity(i);
}
```

This open the wifi settings, and after the user turn on wifi and hit back....
What i need to add to restart the main activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launch `Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS` using `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity`  because when user return back then onActivityResult method called in Activity where you can check again is wifi is enabled or not before restarting Activity.

Start WIFI setting as:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS),0);
```

Override `onActivityResult` method in Activity as:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    if(requestCode==0)
    {
           WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) 
                                     getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if(!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled())
           //restart Application here
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have o do that:

we considered: current Activity = ActivityCurrent
 and   : your main Activity = MainActivity

in your MainActivity do :  MainActivity extends ActivityCurrent

and in your CurrentActivity restard your MainActivity like that:

```
                      Intent intent1 = getIntent();
                      finish();
                      startActivity(intent1);
```